# what type of sigma does corrcov function of matlab return?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3X3 matrix

```
S_2 =

    0.0001   -0.0004    0.0001
   -0.0004    0.0029   -0.0002
    0.0001   -0.0002    0.0003
```

when i apply [R,s] = corrcov(S_2)
it returns a vector with standard deviations sigma in s

```
R =

    1.0000   -0.7834    0.3187
   -0.7834    1.0000   -0.2631
    0.3187   -0.2631    1.0000


s =

    0.0099
    0.0538
    0.0163
```

what type calculation does corrcov perform to get the sigma "s" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspect the source code of corrcov to find out: `edit corrcov.m`

It turns out its: `sigma = sqrt(diag(C))`, where `C` is the input [covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) (the diagonal elements represent the variances, whose square roots are the standard deviations).

Remember that the correlation matrix is the covariance matrix normalized by the standard deviations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_correlation